# iOS - Swift: multi line labels in TableView rows

Tags: swift, uilabel, line-breaks, multiline, word-wrap

I'm trying to insert some multi-line label in a tableview cell, but it looks like in the image below. I would like the text wrapping at line break and occupying more lines as it needs, growing up the height of the cell if necessary.

In the image I would like that every label had the possibility to expand in multiple lines.

The label is embed in a vertical stackview that it's in turn embed in another stackview.

I've tried many many possibilities, including embedding every label in a view, setting 0 to label lines, and other things I found here on SO answers, but no, the labels are not wrapping correctly and they always occupy just one line.

[image]

EDIT:

I add a little explanation:

1) I think the problem is the stackview that it's setting automatically the  height of the children views.

2) Yes, I can use dynamic height cells but that's not the point, cause for me it would be enough to have the cells all the same height, and when the text is not occupying two lines the cell will have more empty space under it. So my problem is just wrapping text of a label embed in a stackview

Comment: So, you want to let the height of the cell to be dynamic right?

Comment: @AhmadF I added an explanation to the question

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like what you are looking for is dynamic cell height, there are a few things that need to happen for that to work:

1) set label lines = 0

2) set the tableview's estimatedRowHeight in viewDidLoad

3) Either after setting the estimatedRowHeight in viewDidLoad set the rowHeight to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or in heightForRow return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

4) Make sure that you do not have height constraints on the labels that you want to change height dynamically

Edited for updated question:

Since the label is in a stack view you want to make sure that the stack view does not have any height constraints and that it will adjust height as needed when the label expands.

Comment: I've tryed everything you mentioned, if I set UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimatedRowHeight the content is not even displayed and the cell is collapsed

Comment: If the cell is collapsed then you are likely not properly setting your constraints in the storyboard. Make sure that you have all the required constraints and that there is a clear connection between the top of the cell contentview with the top label and the bottom with the bottom label. Otherwise the auto size will be 0.

Comment: This is the link that was posted by the other user, it does contain information that would be helpful here, just not what the other user was pointing out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Don't you think its a case of constraint ambiguity? If not just try changing your cell size you will see red error for your constraints then. Because all cells have intrinsic height you need to give priorities.